# Sendgrid template not set using setTemplateId

Tags: sendgrid

I'm not able to use template id for email body in email sent from sendgrid with following code (using 2.2):

```
   val sendgrid = new SendGrid(sendgridapikey)
   val sendgridEmail = new SG.Email()

   sendgridEmail.setSubject("Invitation Email")
   sendgridEmail.setFromName("Sender")
   sendgridEmail.setTemplateId("6305c994-af9a-432e-9a07-5d7f493800e1")
   sendgridEmail.setFrom("no-reply@domain.com")
   sendgridEmail.addTo(to)
  val response = sendgrid.send(sendgridEmail)
```

The email is sent if I remove setTemplateId line above but not with that.
Please help.  thanks!

Comment: What library and language are you using?

Comment: Scala with sendgrid-java » 2.2.2

Comment: Can you try specifying a body in the message as well as the template and see what happens?

Comment: setBody is not a method in 2.2.2. Tried using sendgridEmail.setText(" ")
sendgridEmail.setHtml(" ") along with setTemplateId, still not working. Do we need to locally store the template in the application or we can directly give sendgrid temple id

Comment: I have encountered this issue before.  Try sendgridEmail.setHtml("<span></span>")